# Discord.js V14 none of my slash commands work

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make slash commands and I updated from v13 to v14 I tried to update my deploy commands file but still the same thing none of the commands work and only give me The application did not respond with no errors in the console

deploy.js

```
const path = require('node:path');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token, clientId } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
const isDirectory = source => fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => path.join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);


getDirectories(__dirname + '/slash').forEach(category => {
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(category).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`${category}/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
  }
});

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, "serverid"),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

an example of one of my commands:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton} = require('discord.js');
const {
    kitchen
} = require('../../config.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('status')
        .setDescription('View your order status'),    
    async execute(interaction) {

        interaction.reply("test")
    }

};
```

Comment: Same issue here. Can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `serverid` to variable in here?

Instead of:

```js
await rest.put(
    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, "serverid"),
    { body: commands },
);
```

Try:

```js
await rest.put(
    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, serverid),
    { body: commands },
);
```

Comment: I think `serverid` in this question is a placeholder of the actual server ID, there is no variable called `serverid` somewhere in the code.